# psql /copy “No such file or directory”

Tags: postgresql, csv, copy, psql, postgresql-9.6

I have created a table called "new_test" on my postgres server and I'm trying to copy from a CSV file on my local Mac called "test.csv" to my new table.  Both my "new_test" table and my "test.csv" file have one column called "compkey".  I only have 4 rows in the csv file.  May psql command is as follows:

`\copy new_test(COMPKEY) from ‘TEST.csv’ with delimiter ‘,’ csv header;`

But I keep getting this error message: `‘TEST.csv’: No such file or directory`

I have tried `\cd` to get to the correct filepath and have confirmed I'm in the right folder with `\! ls`, seeing the "TEST.csv" file listed.  I have also tried the absolute path on my Mac, like this:

`\copy new_test(COMPKEY) from '/Users/the/rest/of/the/file/path/TEST.csv’ with delimiter ‘,’ csv header;`

...but I get the same error message.  What am I doing wrong or missing?

Comment: @VaoTsun the only difference I see is using COPY instead of /copy, correct?  The error I get is this: ```ERROR:  must be superuser to COPY to or from a file
HINT:  Anyone can COPY to stdout or from stdin. psql's \copy command also works for anyone.```  I can try ```sudo``` when I start psql and see if it works.

Comment: no - bad copy paste. please try `\copy new_test(COMPKEY) from '/Users/the/rest/of/the/file/path/TEST.csv' with delimiter ',' csv header;` and the diff is leading slash for absolute path

Comment: @VaoTsun this works for me, also.  I didn't realize the leading slash was used to indicate absolute path.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the leading slash in absoluta path. It should start from root. thus the below should work:

```
\copy new_test(COMPKEY) from '/Users/the/rest/of/the/file/path/TEST.csv' with delimiter ',' csv header;
```

article example: https://www.linux.com/blog/absolute-path-vs-relative-path-linuxunix

> An absolute path is defined as the specifying the location of a file
>   or directory from the root directory(/)